# How to find optimum graythresh for im2bw function

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I'm new in image processing. I have a grayscale image like this with 4 circles in middles of each edge:

[image]

I want to check if edges of smaller square halve the circles on them. Other wise, how much distance between center of  the circle and related edge. I wrote below code. First, I try to find length of edge and find the middle of each.

```
BW1=im2bw(image,0.45);
BW1=imcomplement(BW1);

BW1=imclearborder(BW1);
BW1=bwconvhull(BW1);
Area=bwarea(BW1);
side=sqrt(Area);
s              =  regionprops(BW1, 'Centroid');
sx1            =  round(s.Centroid(1));
sy1            =  round(s.Centroid(2));
C1=[sx1,(sy1-side./2)]; %% middle of top edge
C2=[(sx1+side./2),sy1]; %% middle of right edge
C3=[sx1,(sy1+side./2)]; %% middle of bottom edge
C4=[(sx1-side./2),sy1]; %% middle of left edge
```

Then, I find center of each circles like below and I calculate their distance from the related edge:

```
BW2=im2bw(image,0.6);
BW2=bwareaopen(BW2,70);
S      =  regionprops(BW2, 'Centroid');
centroids = round(cat(1, S.Centroid));

D1=centroids(5,:)-C1; %% distance from top edge
D2=centroids(6,:)-C2; %% distance from right edge
D3=centroids(4,:)-C3; %% distance from bottom edge
D4=centroids(3,:)-C4; %% distance from left edge
```

But the problem is that when I change `level` value of  `im2bw`, I get different results. How can I find optimum `level` to have reliable results? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried `graythresh`

Comment: If I use graythresh, I miss the smaller square and all circles.

Answer (score 0):

You can tweak your level and make it depend on the image itself (function of the mean or median etc. for example level=0.5*median(image))

Another way is to [normalize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalization_%28image_processing%29) your images and use a constant value threshold, which you find out yourself depending on your application and data.

Comment: Can you please explain more? I normalize my image but new image totally gets dark.

Comment: how are you normalizing? (try gamma correction if it is too dark to visualize)

Comment: Sorry, I got confused. I  know  very little about image processing. Is there any way to fix my problem instead of normalising?

Comment: Yes try to adjust the level with respect to the image mean or median or variance etc..